# python script for installing boost

Tags: c++, python, boost, build

I used a python script to install boost (without bjam) but I cannot find it anymore. Does anybody know where it is located?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows, do a 'Find' (or download and use Agent Ransack).  If on linux, grep for it.  If it is on your local computer, one of these will find it.